# How to combine multiple CSS files and concatenate JavaScripts if WordPress recommends enqueuing them?

Tags: css, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

How would I go about combining multiple CSS files and concatenating my scripts if they're being enqueued as WordPress recommends? My site is pretty slow and would like to optimize for performance.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't really offer this functionality. You basically grab the array of enqueued scripts + styles and minify & concatenating them before they are output (using 3rd party script), of course you would want to cache this as well. This is quite complicated so I suggest instead:

1. There are several plugins on wordpress.org that do this, just search for "minify".
2. Do this on the server side with something like `mod_pagespeed`
3. Do this on your side with something like [YUI](http://yui.github.com/yuicompressor/)

Comment: Wordpress does have this functionality - you can see it combines its library scripts into one js file before sending to browser. The question is why do they not enable this for plugin/theme scripts?

Comment: Because it would cause to much trouble, WordPress can control the back-end but not a users themes and plugins, so it's then up to the user to do this.